# Nested Routes Showing All Records Instead of Instance Records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, nested-attributes

These are the relevant models:

```
class Repository < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :quizzes, :dependent => :destroy
   has_one :key, :dependent => :destroy

   accepts_nested_attributes_for :key, :quizzes
end

class Quiz < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :repository
   has_many :topics, :dependent => :destroy

   accepts_nested_attributes_for :topics
end
```

This is in my routes:

```
GqAPI::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :repositories do
    resources :quizzes
  end

  resources :quizzes

  resources :keys

  resources :topics

  resources :questions
end
```

When I try this configuration I get all the quizzes in the database, not just the ones for the ID I specify when I try to go to /repositories/1/quizzes

Any ideas on why? Thanks so much for your time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the index action of your `QuizzesController` you need to add:

```
def index
  @repository = Repository.find(params[:repository_id])
  @quizzes = @repository.quizzes
end
```

The `@repository` line will find the repository based on the parameter in your URL. Then it will find all of the quizzes based on that repository.

Then in your view, you can loop through all of those quizzes when you display them.

**Note**

The way you currently have your routes setup, you have the ability to access a page at `/quizzes` but it sounds like you have no desire for this. If this is the case, you can remove `resources: quizzes` from your `routes.rb` (the second one only, not the nested one).

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. However, your suggestion made me realize that I am doing this all wrong... Thanks again!

Comment: Glad I was able to help. It's a learning process. Might want to check out Rails for Zombies at http://codeschool.com I found that pretty useful when I was first starting out.

Comment: Thanks, I am checking it out now!